# How to interpret BIC

Tags: fitting, model, bic

I am fitting two different models to the same data. In one model, there is one free parameter for three different experimental conditions. In another model, I fit three free parameters, one for each condition. I do this for 10 subjects in a dataset.

For each subject, the model with fewer free parameters has a higher BIC. But for every single subject, the difference in BIC is roughly the same (about 10). I find this very suspicious, since the BIC values themselves range from ~30 to ~1000.

I have never used BIC before, and would like to say that the model with one free parameter is better.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing. I have never heard of using BIC on particular subjects. It would usually be used to compare the two models for all 10 subjects. A model fit to one subject would be perfect fit (but meaningless). Also, 3 parameters is rather a lot for 10 subjects.

Comment: I am using the Ratcliff diffusion model, and it is standard practice to fit the model to participants separately. It's not a perfect fit because each subject has ~1000 data points. There are actually more than 3 parameters, but I was trying to keep it simple: in one model, a single parameter is broken down into three and the others remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your further comment, I am not surprised at this result. BIC is a penalized log likelihood. It is useful for comparing models on one data set (here, each participant), but not for comparing across data sets.

What this result is telling you, in essence, is that the model fits very differently for different people, but that the amount of improvement in the fit by adding two parameters is about the same for each person.

Comment: so you are saying that, indeed, i have justification for saying that the model with fewer parameters (higher BIC for all participants) is a "better" model, correct? this was my interpretation, but it seemed strange that the increase in BIC was nearly constant across participants.

Comment: Whether higher or lower is better depends on the implementation. In `SAS` I believe lower is better (it says which is better on the printout). In `R`, as well, a lower BIC is better. From the `R` documentation for AIC: "When comparing fitted objects, the smaller the AIC or BIC, the better the fit. "

Comment: Can´t you use the average square error for predicting numerical targets? If your target is binary, then you can use the cumulative lift or the ROC curve. This is more in line with the SAS output, but i´m sure you can do this with R.